# Pivot Multiple Columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to pivot multiple columns like the table below:

Original Table:

```
ID  ClientName  RegDate     Interest AMT  Principal AMT
1   A           01-Sep-19   100.00        25000.00
1   A           02-Sep-19   200.00        55000.00
2   B           02-Sep-19   300.00        90000.00
2   B           02-Oct-19   400.00        10000.00
2   B           03-Oct-19   500.00        18000.00
```

Expected Result:

```
ID  ClientName  01/09/2019_INT  01/09/2019_Principal 02/09/2019_INT 02/09/2019_Principal    02/10/2019_INT  02/10/2019_Principal    03/10/2019_INT  03/10/2019_Principal
1   A           100.00          25000.00             200.00         55000.00                
2   B                                                300.00         90000.00                400.00          10000.00                500.00          18000.00
```

[Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u0Hh.png)

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSVfD.png)

Comment: Can you also provide the code tried? and which DB is this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Conditional aggregation as a generic case(*as we don't know the DBMS*) :

```
SELECT ID, ClientName, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN RegDate = '2019-09-01' THEN InterestAMT END) AS "2019-09-01_INT",
       MAX(CASE WHEN RegDate = '2019-09-01' THEN PrincipalAMT END) AS "2019-09-01_Principal",
       MAX(CASE WHEN RegDate = '2019-09-02' THEN InterestAMT END) AS "2019-09-02_INT",
       MAX(CASE WHEN RegDate = '2019-09-02' THEN PrincipalAMT END) AS "2019-09-02_Principal",
       MAX(CASE WHEN RegDate = '2019-09-03' THEN InterestAMT END) AS "2019-09-03_INT",
       MAX(CASE WHEN RegDate = '2019-09-03' THEN PrincipalAMT END) AS "2019-09-03_Principal"       
  FROM t
 GROUP BY ID, ClientName
```

`PIVOT` clause might also be used for some DBMS. the date literals should be preceded by `date` for Oracle such as `date'2019-09-01'` instead of `'2019-09-01'`

Comment: Just a note, that preceding `DATE` keyword is according to ISO/ANSI SQL.

Comment: BTW, doesn't your 2:nd and 3rd column look a little too similar?

Comment: thnaks @jarlh fixed the mixed column names. `date` cannot be used for MSSQL, and redundant for MySQL or Postgres, but required for Oracle.